# retrieving pid in unix startup script

Tags: unix, pid

in a simple startup script I wrote I have:

```
PID=`su user_name -c "daemon_name > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$!"`  
echo $PID
```

The script is run as `root`. And the echo doesn't really echo anything :)

If I input the exact same command in the shell, it works:

```
# su user_name -c "daemon_name > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$!"  
11831  
#
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: It was working fine before I tried to run the application as another user.
I was previously using this code:

```
PID=`daemon_name > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`  
echo $PID
```

and it worked fine as `root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

daemons are designed to fork multiple times so likely the PID returned from $! will not be the pid you want to work with later. You will probably have to do something like this:

```
ps -eo pid,command,lstart --sort lstart | grep 'daemon_name' | tail -1
```

Comment: No forking in this scenario. The program I named `daemon_name` is in fact a java standalone application that I want to run "as a daemon". In the real case `daemon_name` is actually a `startup.sh` script that starts a java application.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this: `ps ho pid --sort lstart -C daemon_name | tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

Try $$ instead of $! (current pid instead of last)

Comment: That's not what I want I'm afraid. Maybe I wasn't too clear in the original question. I need the pid relevant to the execution of the `daemon_name` program. If I try your solution, i get a pid echoed, but when then I grep the running processes I get another pid: the two pids don't match.

Comment: Pretty sure the backticks will run and then finish before returning to your script. It sounds like you want to execute this as a sub-shell or background process.